# How to get MongoDB database stats with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get MongoDB stats such as total database size for health metrics using mongoose, but haven't been able to do so.

I found [this](https://codedump.io/share/RdU7fICr06Wo/1/mongoose-dbstats-equivalent) piece of code. but it doesn't seem to work.

db.js:

```js
const db = mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URL, settings, (err) => {
  mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
  logger.info(`connecting ${config.MONGODB_URL}`);
  if (err) {
    logger.error(`failed db connection: ${err}`);
  }
});

module.exports = db;
```

monitor.js:

```js
const db = require('../store/db');

function mongoUsage(cb) {
  db.db.stats((err, data) => {
    logger.debug(data);
  });
  cb();
}
```

However I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'stats' of undefined` error when running the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you have to **make sure at first that your database connection has been established**. In the provided example, you may notice `db.once` call which waits for `open` event to occur. In other words, we have a pending connection to the database running and the goal is to get notified if we connect successfully. Therefore, your connection object is still in the process of its creation, and thus `undefined` yet.

Try to modify your files accordingly assuming you have defined `logger`, `config` and `settings` appropriately:

db.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URL, settings, (err) => {
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
    logger.info(`connecting ${config.MONGODB_URL}`);
    if (err) {
      logger.error(`failed db connection: ${err}`);
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.connection;
```

monitor.js:

```
const db = require('../store/db');

db.once('open', () => {
  // call stats directly
  db.db.stats((err, data) => {
    logger.debug(data);

  });

  // or you can call your mongoUsage here
});
```

With the code above I succesfully get the following result:

```
{ db: 'test-db',
  collections: 1,
  views: 0,
  objects: 1,
  avgObjSize: 844,
  dataSize: 844,
  storageSize: 36864,
  numExtents: 0,
  indexes: 6,
  indexSize: 221184,
  fsUsedSize: 2271096832,
  fsTotalSize: 19163181056,
  ok: 1 }
```

I hope it helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: Trying that I now get `TypeError: db.once is not a function`

Comment: Is your db.js in line with the answer ? I have changed the exports to mongoose.connection instead of db object as you had done previously.

Comment: Oh no what a derp I am. It works now! Thanks a lot :)